Error in IntelliJ when having jasmine *and* cypress tests
When having jasmine and cypress tests in an (angular) project, some type definitions are in conflict with each other. It's possible to handle this in the build by maintaining different typescript configuration files for *.spec.ts and *.cy.ts files.
But IntelliJ always knows all dependencies and chooses the first one, which is always cypress. Therefore it always shows problems in the jasmine files, e.g. for a line expect(myVar).toEqual(2); it complains with TS2551: Property toEqual does not exist on type Assertion.
tsconfig.spec.json:
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}

tsconfig.app.json:
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}

tsconfig.json:
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}

Similarly, auto-completion is not working for expectations.
How can this be handled?

Please provide your tsconfig.json, tsconfig.spec.json and cypress/tsconfig.json

I included the relevant files up there - no cypress/tsconfig.json.
IDEA 2024 1.4 doesn't complain about problems any more, but auto-completion still is not working.

Where are these tsconfig placed in the folder structure?

they're all in the root folder
